# How do I implement the 'FROM' input in SQL to pull information from my project? Screenshot in description

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I'm taking a coursera course on Data Analytics and following along with the video but I'm not sure why Im receiving an error message or how the video is getting the 'tethers' option?

I attached a screenshot of what Im trying to do and as you can see, line 4 has an error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsJ5j.jpg)

The second screenshot is from the video in the course.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27EhM.jpg)

Thanks

I'm really not sure what else to try, I right clicked the 3 dots next do my project name hoping I could create a tether, but I'm not sure how that works they never went over it in the google course

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question.  I deleted the single parenthesis on each side and now it works.